# How can I add a data-attr to each option within an entity field type in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to work out how I can add a data-attr to each of my options within an entity type field. I have looked through the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) and can't seem to find any simple way of adding this.

Comment: Since entity type inherits from choice, you might adapt example from https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3836 ,though not sure if there's a simple way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add attributes to options in symfony out of the box. But you could look into writing your own custom field type, see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html